# zendframework fetchPairs equivalent function in doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Zend db table adapter provides fetchPairs function which return pairs of array( id=>idvalue, ...),

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select()->from('users', array('id', 'username'));
$roleOptions = $db->fetchPairs($select);
```

which can be loaded in zend form element

```
$this->addElement('select', 'user', array(
            'label'      => 'Select user:',
            'required'   => true,
            'multiOptions' => $roleOptions
        ));
```

Which equivalent function is available in Doctrine?

I know we can do this by looping through the record set :)

But I want to do this in right way using doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is looping through the objects.

```
$q = $em->createQuery("select u from MyApp\Domain\User u");
foreach ($q->getResult() as $user){
    //process it here
}
```

The not-so-right way: [partial objects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/partial-objects.html)

```
$q = $em->createQuery("select partial u.{id,name} from MyApp\Domain\User u");
foreach ($q->getResult() as $user){
    //process it here the same way as above
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` mode with doctrine as explained [here](https://www.thedevfiles.com/2014/08/simplifying-database-interactions-with-doctrine-dbal/).

Example:

`$statement = $connection->query('SELECT id, username FROM users');
$pairs     = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);`

Answer (score 0):

In repository class, method's body

```php
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('t.id, t.param1, t.param2')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 't INDEX BY t.id');

$res =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And the $result will contain

```
array(
    1 => array(
        id = 1,
        param1= val2,
        param2=val2
    ),
    ...,
    234 => array(
        id = 234,
        param1= val234,
        param2=val234
    )
);
```

see also [using-index-by](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by)